# Can I deploy ASP.NET 4.0 application on Windows XP?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I want to start a small project. The target platform on which I have to deploy my system is Windows XP. I want to develop it in ASP.NET 4.0. Can I deploy ASP.NET 4.0 application on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have Service Pack 3 installed, you can install the .Net framework v4.0 on windows XP.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en